# How to stop email signature being pulled through

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that will give me disk space sizes for one of my servers, and will then email the result to me, however it keeps pulling through the signature into the tables.

I just found this script and edited parts to match what I need so I'm not too sure where to look to stop this happening.

I've copied the whole thing as I have no idea where it's going wrong, sorry!

I've tried removing the key that was in there as this is where it was originally adding the signature, however it's now just populating the signature in another table.

[This is what it's doing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwgAi.png)

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue";
$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition 
$dir = Split-Path $scriptpath 

#Variables to configure
$percentWarning = 25;
$percentCritcal = 15;
$smtpServer = "ip" 
$ReportSender = "administrator@company.com"  
$users = "tech@company.com"; 
$MailSubject = "DiskSpace Report for $titledate"

#No change needed from here!!!
$reportPath = "$dir\Logs\"
$reportName = "DiskSpaceRpt_$(get-date -format ddMMyyyy).html";
$diskReport = $reportPath + $reportName
$redColor = "#FF0000"
$orangeColor = "#FBB917"
$whiteColor = "#FFFFFF"
$greenColor = "#7FFF00"
$i = 0;
$computers = Get-Content "$dir\servers_list.txt";
$datetime = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy_HHmmss";

If (Test-Path $diskReport)
{
Remove-Item $diskReport
}
$titleDate = get-date -uformat "%m-%d-%Y - %A"
$header = "
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>
<title>DiskSpace Report</title>
<STYLE TYPE='text/css'>
<!--
table {
border: thin solid #666666;
}
td {
font-family: Tahoma;
font-size: 11px;
border-top: 1px solid #999999;
border-right: 1px solid #999999;
border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
border-left: 1px solid #999999;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
}
body {
margin-left: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
table {
border: thin solid #000000;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table width='100%'>
<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
<td colspan='7' height='25' align='center'>
<font face='tahoma' color='#003399' size='4'><strong>DiskSpace Report for $titledate</strong></font>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
"
Add-Content $diskReport $header
$tableHeader = "
<table width='100%'><tbody>
<tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC>
<td width='10%' align='center'>Server</td>
<td width='5%' align='center'>Drive Label</td>
<td width='15%' align='center'>Drive</td>
<td width='10%' align='center'>Total Capacity(GB)</td>
<td width='10%' align='center'>Used Capacity(GB)</td>
<td width='10%' align='center'>Free Space(GB)</td>
<td width='5%' align='center'>Freespace %</td>
</tr>
"

Add-Content $diskReport $tableHeader
foreach($computer in $computers)
{   
$disks = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Class Win32_Volume -Filter "DriveType = 3" | Where-Object {$_.Label -ne "System Reserved"}
$computer = $computer.toupper()
foreach($disk in $disks)
{        
$deviceID = $disk.Label;
$volName = $disk.Name;
[float]$size = $disk.Capacity;
[float]$freespace = $disk.FreeSpace; 
$percentFree = [Math]::Round(($freespace / $size) * 100, 2);
$sizeGB = [Math]::Round($size / 1073741824, 2);
$freeSpaceGB = [Math]::Round($freespace / 1073741824, 2);
$usedSpaceGB = [Math]::Round($sizeGB - $freeSpaceGB, 2);
$color = $greenColor;
if($percentFree -lt $percentWarning)      
{
$color = $orangeColor   
if($percentFree -lt $percentCritcal)
{
$color = $redColor
}
}        
$dataRow = "
<tr>
<td width='10%'>$computer</td>
<td width='5%' align='center'>$deviceID</td>
<td width='15%' >$volName</td>
<td width='10%' align='center'>$sizeGB</td>
<td width='10%' align='center'>$usedSpaceGB</td>
<td width='10%' align='center'>$freeSpaceGB</td>
<td width='5%' bgcolor=`'$color`' align='center'>$percentFree</td>
</tr>
"
Add-Content $diskReport $dataRow;
Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow "$computer $deviceID percentage free space = $percentFree";
$i++        
}
}
#$tableDescription = "
# </table><br><table width='20%'>
#   <tr bgcolor='White'>
#   <td width='10%' align='center' bgcolor='#FBB917'>Warning less than $percentWarning% free space</td>
#<td width='10%' align='center' bgcolor='#FF0000'>Critical less than $percentCritcal% free space</td>
#</tr>
#"
Add-Content $diskReport $tableDescription
Add-Content $diskReport "</body></html>"
if ($i -gt 0)
{
foreach ($user in $users)
{
Write-Host "Sending Email notification to $user"

$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$msg = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$msg.To.Add($user)
$msg.From = $ReportSender
$msg.Subject = $MailSubject
$msg.IsBodyHTML = $true
$msg.Body = get-content $diskReport
$smtp.Send($msg)
$body = ""
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a utility, after your script, as appending a standard disclaimer.

Not sure about it's removal, but to fix the table so it appears at the bottom, and not in the middle of your data, you need t complete and end the table.

When you commented out $tableDescription, you lost the HTML of 
`"</table>"`

As a result, the email is sent with the table still open.  The HTML processor tries to add the disclaimer text added by your email system, and this is what you end up with.

At a minimum, TableDescription needs to be:

```
$tableDescription = "</table>"
```

Best way to troubleshoot this problem in the future is to look at the email in plan text (or RAW text on some email clients).

There you can see any missing HTML syntax, such as

`<</table>,</tr> or </td>` tags if they are missing.